# How to have approx_fprime return an array (multiple values) instead of scalar?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to figure out how I can get approx_fprime to return multiple values, instead of just a scalar.

Let's say your doing error propagation through a system of equations:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, approx_fprime
def pipeline2(inp):
    sol1,sol1A,sol1B,sol1AB=inp
    def equations(initial):
            x,y,k1,k=initial
            sol1_equation=((k*k1)/(1+k1))-sol1
            sol1A_equaiton=((k*k1*x**2)/(1+k1*x))-sol1A
            sol1B_equation=((k*k1*y**2)/(1+k1*y))-sol1B
            sol1AB_equation=((k*k1*x**2*y**2)/(1+k1*x*y))-sol1AB
            return(sol1_equation,sol1A_equaiton,sol1B_equation,sol1AB_equation)
    val1,val2,val3,val4=fsolve(equations,(7,30,0.02,500))
    return np.array([val1,val2,val3,val4])
```

Now normally I return an array, because I can easily calculate the partial derivatives of all values all at once as such

```
h=1e-10
differential=np.array([(pipeline2(sol1_value+h,sol1A_value,sol1B_value,sol1AB_value)-pipeline2(sol1_value,sol1A_value,sol1B_value,sol1AB_value))/h,(pipeline2(sol1_value,sol1A_value+h,sol1B_value,sol1AB_value)-pipeline2(sol1_value,sol1A_value,sol1B_value,sol1AB_value))/h,(pipeline2(sol1_value,sol1A_value,sol1B_value+h,sol1AB_value)-pipeline2(sol1_value,sol1A_value,sol1B_value,sol1AB_value))/h,(pipeline2(sol1_value,sol1A_value,sol1B_value,sol1AB_value+h)-pipeline2(sol1_value,sol1A_value,sol1B_value,sol1AB_value))/h])
```

This provides a matrix of partial derivatives for all 4 variables, for all 4 sol1s (4x4 matrix). Naturally, while the output is nice and clean, the required code to generate it is ugly (this long line). Hence why I'd prefer to use approx_fprime (no point in reinventing the wheel here if it does the same thing I want).

However, approx_fprime returns a scalar only.

Anyone have any suggestions how I can calculate the partial derivatives for val1,val2,val3,val4 with respect to sol1,sol1A,sol1B,sol1AB in an elegant fashion using approx_fprime, say in one line like I have setup?

Comment: The docs say that `approx_fprime` returns an array.

Comment: It returns an array of a scalar value. So in the above setup, it would return the array of partial derivatives of val1 with respect to sol. Where val1 is a scalar value. What I'd like is for it to return the array(s) of all val with respect to sol. Not just a single one

Answer (score 0):

`approx_fprime` is already returning a Jacobian:

```
from scipy.optimize import approx_fprime

def f(x):
    x1, x2 = x
    return x1**2 + 2 * x2, x1**3 + x2**2

J = approx_fprime([2, 3], f)
print(J)
```

gives

```
[[ 4.  2.]
 [12.  6.]]
```

Check that your scipy version is recent.